# Dynamic layout based on roles

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am building a website where the user can login .I am using materialise-css and Angularjs for front end and java-hibernate backend(using spring is not an option in my case)

The user can be admin, manager or employee. I want different views for different login roles as shown below.

For admin
[image]

For manager
[image]

and Employee
[image]

**My question is:**

Is it a good approach to redirect to 3 different index.html or the page can be loaded dynamically based on the roles.If dynamically can be done, how? I have read about using `ng-show` and `ng-if`. But I am not understanding how to design the page with proper alignment and all with that. Please help me with proper answer for redirect me to any useful resource. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far so we can help.

Comment: umm actually i have all the partials of the display components now .And i want to integrate everthing in the index page.So isnt it like the initial stage to post what i have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes dynamically is possible, and a much better idea for achieving what you're aiming to get out of your app.

Look into a concept called [nested states or views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) within angular, and the module you'd use to achieve this is [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld). Have a look at the `ui-router` [sample app](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1). (... as its very in depth, and covers most of the scenarios you're likely to encounter)

It'll allow you structure you app something like: 
*(app could be an abstract view, with just general themes, context specific menus, global shared functionality, for example)*

- `app` *(index.html, app.js)*

  - `/admin` *(admin.view.html, admin.controller.js)*
  - `/manager` *(manager.view.html, manager.controller.js)*
  - `/employee` *(employee.view.html, employee.controller.js)*

    - `/task_type/id` *(employeeTask.view.html, employeeTask.controller.js)*

You could go as granular as you need to logically section off your application for each purpose. I've used an angular module called [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission) in the sample below, but there are multiple ways you can solve this, even using hooks exposed native to ui-router only, but it might require a little bit more upfront effort.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true, // an abstract state is one you can navigate to directly. its a container for child views such as a "master" page
        url: '/foo',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('app.admin', {
        // url will become '/foo/admin'
        url: '/admin',
        data: {
          permissions: {
            only: ['isAdmin']
          }
        }
    })
    .state('app.manager', {
        // url will become '/foo/manager'
        url: '/manager',
        data: {
          permissions: {
            only: ['isAdmin', 'isManager']
          }
        }
    })
    .state('app.employee', {
        // url will become '/foo/employee'
        url: '/employee',
        data: {
          permissions: {
            only: ['isAdmin', 'isManager', 'isEmployee']
          }
        }
    })
    .state('app.employee.task', {
        // url will become '/foo/employee/sometask/1'
        url: '/:task/:id',
        data: {
          permissions: {
            only: ['isAdmin', 'isManager', 'isEmployee']
          }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
          $scope.taskType = $scope.contacts[$stateParams.task];
          $scope.taskId = $scope.contacts[$stateParams.id];
        }
    })
```

In the above, you can see that certain routes are restricted to certain user types, you'll also have a much more modular code base and allow certain partial section to focus on only their own responsibility. eg `app.employee.task` would be used to display data thats only concerns itself with employee tasks. (as opposed to having a monolith html display all page)

Comment: @vikk did the above help you / did you resolve your question?

Comment: yes partially ..Just wanted to ask one thing before i accept the answer.For each user role my UI changes,ie for some people there are additional data to be displayed.So Should i have 3 different html for 3 roles or am i understanding the route part wrong ?

Comment: @vikk, yes you should... but their pages could be seen as partial pages. (eg they'll only include the html unique to them) The router would swap out the controller & html as needed as the user navigates. I'll update my answer a little to demonstrate

Comment: Yes please ,else if u can redirect me to a fiddle or something that would be great..

Comment: @vikk please see the updated section with the app structure. also clone this repo (as stated in my answer). and go through the code. It's REALLY good, and I believe its easy to follow: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot ..i will get back to you if i find any issue when i code